# Set designed Tframe on some Tpanel

Tags: c++, delphi, forms, vcl, tframe

I am totally novice in C++ Builder.
Never tried working with VCL frames.

So, i have some Tform with Tpanel and two frames designed.

How can i display designed frames on my forms panel?

Tired searching similar examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know C++ builder, but I've heard it uses the exact same Form Designer that Delphi has.  In Delphi, to place a frame on the form, you need to create the frame first and have it in your project.  Then go to the component palette and find the "Frames" option under the **Standard** group.  Select it and it'll give you a dialog box containing all the frames in your project.  Pick which one from there and you've got an instance of the frame on your form, which you can manipulate just like any other control.